# How to offer a 'confirm' dialog which then fires server-side code

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I have been given the task to re-code an old VB6 page.  This page exports data from our database and imports it into another.  While the export/import is happening, I need to offer the user confirm boxes.  The context and results of these confirm boxes all depend on server-side validation.  In the old code, the author simply did:

```
If MsgBox(Msg, vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    GoTo Function1
Else
    GoTo Function2
End If
```

Yes, those are GoTos, don't remind.  This code is rough.  Anyway, how in the heck can I do this in .NET with c# code behind?

Comment: is this an asp.net page?

Answer (score 1):

Well the code would be the same if it were C#, though it would look something like:

```
if (Interaction.MsgBox(Msg, Constants.vbOKCancel) == Constants.vbOK) {
    goto Function1;
}
else {
    goto Function2;
}
```

But, if this is an ASP.NET application, it would look different. You'd probably make a modal dialog box and attach some click handlers to the buttons on that dialog.

[edit]
By the way, if you're ever in doubt about how VB code would look in C#, try a converter utility such as [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) one. They don't work all the time, but they work sometimes. Cheers.